# error migrating contract with inheritance using truffle

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, truffle, nft

I get this error when trying to migrate a contract with an inheritance

Error: "NFTCollectible" -- Invalid number of parameters for "undefined". Got 0 expected 1!.

/contracts/NFTCollectible.sol

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Counters.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/math/SafeMath.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721Enumerable.sol";

contract NFTCollectible is ERC721Enumerable, Ownable {
        using SafeMath for uint256;
        using Counters for Counters.Counter;
        ...    
    }
```

/migrations/2_deploy_contracts.js

```
var NFTCollectible = artifacts.require("NFTCollectible");

module.exports = function(deployer) {
    deployer.deploy(NFTCollectible);
};
```

Comment: does NFTCollectible has constructor?

Comment: https://dev.to/rounakbanik/writing-an-nft-collectible-smart-contract-2nh8

Hi T@Yilmaz I am not sure, there is a section called Final contract on the link
that's the exact contact I'm working with 

I need to learn more about smart contract syntax to be sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is the NFTCollectible contract on the page:

[image]

so this contract has a constructor method and it requires 1 argument. so when you deploy the contract, you have to pass the parameter to the conract as below:

```
var NFTCollectible = artifacts.require("NFTCollectible");

module.exports = function(deployer) {
    // you have to pass the baseURI
    deployer.deploy(NFTCollectible,"https://baseUriHere");
};
```